# which xml file is used for which android activity?

Tags: android

I have one android application.I am trying to make one function that will return activity names and corresponding XML file.
(XML is set by `setContentView(R.layout.abc)`).
suppose i have 5 Activity and 5 XML files in application, how to find out which activity is using which XML file? Is there any way to find out "XML name"  corresponding "activity" without going inside code of activity. I want output like this,

1. Main_Activity have activity_main.XML
2. `abc_Activity`have `xyz.XML`
3. `pqr_Activity` have `efg.XML`

Comment: i dont think it can be done!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to your question:-

1. Get the **list of all activities** exposed by the application, which can be done as below:-

   ```
   private void getActivityList() throws NameNotFoundException {
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
           PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
           PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.packagename",
                           PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
           ApplicationInfo test = info.applicationInfo;
           ActivityInfo[] list = info.activities;
   }
   ```
2. Get the **XML(layouts)** associated with them. This I don't think is possible.